# Do I use the postgres 'default administrative connection database' to house my schema?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, odp.net, npgsql

We are attempting to convert our Oracle database to PostgreSQL (due to Oracle's ludicrous pricing model). The system is not in production yet but will soon so this needs to be done ASAP. Thank goodness we don't use that many Oracle database specific features and treat it mostly as a data store from out .NET applications in C#. As a replacement for OPD.Net we are looking at using the  [Data Provider for PostgreSQL, Npgsql.NET](http://www.npgsql.org/).

Now I have installed PostgreSQL 9.5 on my Windows 2012 R2 server and want to create my first set of tables. I run PgAdmin III and login and am presented with a postgres 'default administrative connection database', now what?

I have read [Database Schema Recommendations for an Application](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Database_Schema_Recommendations_for_an_Application) but that page was last modified over 3 years ago and starts at the wrong point - for instance, do I use the postgres 'default administrative connection database' to house my schema? Or do I create another database? Is there a naming convention? I will probably use multiple schema's housed in one database but would appreciate any recommendations or best practices for creating PostgreSQL databases and schemas.

Lastly, any pointers for converting from Oracle? I have read [Oracle to PostgreSQL Conversion](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion) but again, out of date - only considers Oracle 8. Anything that considers Oracle 12c? Anything that explains PostgreSQL in Oracle developer and DBA terms?

Comment: The "*default administrative connection database*" is specific to the _tool_ you are using (pgAdmin), not Postgres itself. I don't use pgAdmin but I think you can just skip that step. The `postgres` database is nothing special and can be used for your regular data without any restrictions. If you don't like it create a different one.

Comment: It's best that you simply create a database of your own (with some descriptive name) and create all your schemas and tables in there. Beyond that there's nothing special really.